# In Perl, how do I ensure that a sub is invoked as a method from methods of the same object?

Tags: perl

I have a class  that has a new method and uses that object to call method X.  When I call X from the object the first value of the parameters is $self and the rest are the values I sent in.  Now when I call that same method from another method on the object the first value is no longer $self and its just the values being sent in. How do I address this situation?

Sample:

```
my $p = TEST->new;
$p->mymethod(1,2,3);  # @_ = 'self, 1, 2, 3'
```

but if in 'mymethod' is called by another method:

```
sub anothermethod{
  my ($self, $a) = @_;
  mymethod(1,2,3);  # @_ = '1,2,3'  
}
```

How do I write 'mymethod' so it handle both situations?  Or am I fundamentally doing something incorrect?

Comment: What about `$self->mymethod(1, 2, 3)` instead?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just as you did this:

```
$p->mymethod(1,2,3);
```

you need to be explicit about what object you are calling the method on (even within the class):

```
$self->mymethod(1,2,3);
```

Comment: In http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35281526/seek-perl-idiom-to-check-that-self-is-a-class-or-object @schwern provided a nice chunk of code that can be used inside mymethod to ensure that it is called as $self->mymethod(1,2,3) rather than as a sub mymethod(1,2,3). The accepted answer just says what the programmer using mymethod should write, whereas schwern's approach detects such errors.

Answer (score 2):

This is Not A Good Idea (you ought to decide whether a subroutine is a method or not and use it in a consistent way), but in moments of weakness I have used constructions like:

```
sub subroutine_that_may_get_called_like_a_method {
    shift if ref $_[0] eq __PACKAGE__;
    my ($param1, $param2) = @_;
    ...
}

sub method_that_may_get_called_like_a_subroutine {
    unshift @_, __PACKAGE__ if ref $_[0] ne __PACKAGE__
    my ($self, $param1, $param2) = @_;
    ...
}
```

Usually I can only stare at this code for a few hours before the shame pools in my gut and I have to fix it.

Comment: I assume that @mob is saying that the code he provides is a dirty trick.

Comment: I have also been tempted to create subroutines that may get called like methods, and vice versa.  If you think about it, C++'s class static methods are exactly that: they may be called as Class::method(...) or object->method(), and in neither case is a this (Perl's convention $self) created.  //  I think that such class methods can be a good idea in general, but implementing them in Perl is unsafe:   you cannot distinguish $foo0->m($foo1,$foo2) from Foo::m($foo1,$foo2,$foo3).

Comment: Why class methods (like C++ class static methods) are good in general: I often see the pattern "package of subroutines that needs to be transparently substituted for a different package of subroutines".  As well as "originally a stateless class, but now I need stateful objects, with a default if no object specified." The Class::function() syntax does not support such evolution.  Class->function() does.  But then you need your "method_that_may_get_called_like_a_subroutine" approach, to provide the default object if the latter pattern.

Comment: In C++ a class method can be called like an instance method, but the class method will not and cannot make use of the instance that invoked it (there will be no `this` pointer in a static method). Perl doesn't have C++'s function signature type checking (and no, Perl's prototypes are a poor substitute for this) and so the OP's confusion is possible.