# Seek Perl idiom to check that $self is a class or object

Tags: perl, oop

In Perl, I just got bitten by something that looked like the bug below:

```
package Foo;
sub method {
    my $self = shift;
    my @args = @_;
    ...
}
```

where I called it as a subroutine, not a method:

```
Foo::method( "arg1", "arg2" );
```

rather than calling it as a method - in this case, it was a "class method":

```
Foo->method( "arg1", "arg2" );
```

Calling Foo::method("arg1","arg2")  resulted in "arg1" getting dropped.

Similar considerations can arise with an "object method":

```
my $object = Foo->new();
$obj->method( "arg1", "arg2" );
```

Is there a friendly, concise, Perl idiom for checking that the first argument, conventionally called `$self`, is in fact an object in the class (package), and/or the class/package name?

The best I have come up with is:

```
package Foo;
sub method {
    my $self = ($_[0]->isa(__PACKAGE__) ? shift @_ : die "...error message...";
    my @args = @_;
    ...
}
```

which is not much more concise than

```
package Foo;
sub method {
    my $self = shift;
    die "...error message..."  if $self->isa(__PACKAGE__);
    my @args = @_;
    ...
}
```

or

```
package Foo;
use Carp::Assert;
sub method {
    my $self = shift;
    assert($self->isa(__PACKAGE__));
    my @args = @_;
    ...
}
```

---

Notes:

I know about Perl signatures, but dislike using experimental features.

I know about [`use attributes` and `:method`](http://perldoc.perl.org/attributes.html).   Is that the best way to go?   Similar concerns about "evolving" features.

I know about Moose - but I don't think that Moose enforces this.  (Did I miss anything.)

The problem with Perl is that there are so many ways to do something.

Comment: methods that could be either a class method or an instance method are a misfeature IMO

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7728417/in-perl-how-do-i-ensure-that-a-sub-is-invoked-as-a-method-from-methods-of-the-s/7728797#7728797

Comment: @ysth: "methods that could be either a class method or an instance method are a misfeature" - no kidding!  But Perl inherently supports them, and I am trying to find a way to prevent them from causing bugs.

Comment: @ysth  Why? Because of the issues raised in the question or are there other reasons as well?

Comment: Sorry. To/From confusion. Fixed and reposted.

Comment: @G.Cito: I do not understand why you asked "Why?" Surely "preventing bugs" is a good reason for many things in programming if the prevention is easy, cheap, understandable, etc.

Comment: @G.Cito: - or are you referring to ""methods that could be either a class method or an instance method are a misfeature". Actually, I am less string on that than you are, as I explain in a response to stackoverflow.com/questions/7728417/… - standard refactorings often lead to what amount to "class static methods"

Comment: @G.Cito it just adds potential for bugs without actually giving any benefit

Comment: Thanks. I assumed calling method as a function would somehow not work at compile time (perhaps some modules check signatures in some rudimentary way?), but calling a function as a method might be problematic since it could compile but break at run-time due to improper function args and the like.

Comment: @KrazyGlew :-) Yes I was commenting in regard to @ysth's notion of misfeature.  OO terminology seems to come from  many different sources (class method, class static method, private function `_private`, *etc.*) and I often find much to like in perl's relaxed approach.

Comment: @G.Cito calling a method as a function would also compile but break at run-time due to improper function args and the like

Comment: @ysth: the whole point of my question is that calling a method as a function compiles, and runs without error (sometimes). Runs incorrectly, but runs nevertheless. I prefer buggy code to die cleanly.

Answer (score 10):

The best answer is to not mix functions and methods in a single package.  "Hybrid modules", as they're known, are problematic.  Everything which you might want to make a function should instead be a class method call.

There should be little need to fully qualify a function call in day-to-day programming.

---

The most concise way is to use [Moops](https://metacpan.org/pod/Moops) which is the new way to use Moose with syntax-sugar.

```
use Moops;

class Foo {
    method something() {
        print("something called\n");
    }
}

Foo->new->something();
Foo::something();

# something called
# Invocant $self is required at /Users/schwern/tmp/test.plx line 10.
```

[Moops is marked as unstable](https://metacpan.org/pod/Moops#STATUS), but that's the interface, not the signatures themselves. Signatures have been around and usable in production for a long time, longer than they've been built in.  More worrying is there [hasn't been a release in over a year](https://metacpan.org/changes/distribution/Moops), however the author writes good stuff.  Your call.

---

Otherwise, like with anything else, write a function.

```
use Carp;
use Scalar::Util qw(blessed);

sub check_invocant {
    my $thing = shift;

    my $caller = caller;

    if( !defined $thing ) {
        croak "The invocant is not defined";
    }
    elsif( !ref $thing ) {
        croak "The invocant is not a reference";
    }
    elsif( !blessed $thing ) {
        croak "The invocant is not an object";
    }
    elsif( !$thing->isa($caller) ) {
        croak "The invocant is not a subclass of $caller";
    }

    return $thing;
}
```

Since this returns the invocant and handles the exception for you it can be used very concisely.

```
package Foo;

sub method {
    my $self = ::check_invocant(shift);

    ...
}
```

Comment: @Schern: I agree on not mixing functions and methods in a single package. This bug occurred as I was refactoring from a "package of functions" to a class - although I suppose I was not really refactoring, since this bug occurred, and my tests all passed.  My tests all passed, but not all of the callers (in separate code trees) got changed - I suppose I should not have refactored in place, but should have created a new class package, and forwarded from old to new.  But the one ends up with all sorts of package names that are slightly different from each other.

Comment: if you separate the "use (unstable) Moops" from the "use something like this check_invocant function", I will accept the latter as an answer - assuming nothing better pops up in next few days.  I was somewhat hoping that there was already a package that had check_invocant() in it, since I am guessing that there will need to be several flavors needed.

Comment: BTW, C++ has class methods and object methods.  A class method can be called as Class::method() or as obj->method(), and in the latter there is no "self" or "this" created implicitly.  check_invocant's !ref prevents a "class method" from being called via the Class->method() syntax in Perl, since the class name string is first argument. Easy to "fix", but it worries me that you cannot then distinguish Foo->m($foo1,$foo2) from Foo::m("Foo",$foo1,$foo2),   or $foo1->m($foo2) from Foo::($foo1,$foo2).  Probably Perl's bad  - if the package string were somehow flavored, could make safe(r).

Comment: @KrazyGlew I'm not going to split the answer, I gave a choice of answers for a reason. The first because I think the bug is rare and adding a check to every method is not good use of dev or CPU time; Perl's lackadaisical OO system does require some getting used to. The second so you're aware of the state of the art; signatures have been around for a long time, are quite usable in production, and you shouldn't be doing OO by hand anyway. The third because it's what you asked for.

Answer (score 2):

I'll add to what Schwern has written to say that you could also take a look at [Safe::Isa](https://metacpan.org/pod/Safe::Isa), which lets you safely call `isa` on something which you cannot be sure is an object.

Comment: thanks: Safe::Isa is halfway to what a package useful for this limited form of argumnt checking would need.  Although...  I am more and more in the Andrei Alexandrescu camp, the best way to indicate an error is to throw an exception. It is unfortunate that exceptions lead to such ugly error messages - I would probably write an argument checking package mainly to provide a more useful error message, like "method: first argument ($self) was not an object of the expected class".  And then throw that string as an exception.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to try to follow the advice of @Schwern and "not mix functions and methods in a single package". That said, here's an example using the `fun` `method` approach from [`Function::Parameters`](http://metacpan.org/pod/Function::Parameters). The example is of course contrived and a bit awkward, but it illustrates the idea.

`Function::Parameters` requires a compiler version of at least `perl5.14`. It's still perl (and XS) so it will not magically make your code "strongly typed". But, with `attributes` and type constraints via `Type::Tiny`, you *can* separate your methods and functions by more than name only. Even just using different names for different types of subroutines - `fun` and `method` by default - can be really helpful.

Using the `':strict'` keyword and/or default function/method "types" (`fun => { ... }` and `method => { ... }` below, as well as others such as `method_lax`) obviates the need for passing values to settings when the module is imported, so the code below can be made shorter.

```
use v5.22;   
package My::Package {
  use DDP;
  use attributes 'get';
  use Function::Parameters { 
    fun    =>  { strict => 1, } , 
    method =>  { strict => 1,
                 invocant => 1, 
                 shift => '$class', 
                 attributes => ':method',} ,  
  } ;

  fun func_test ( @ )  {
   warn "must be called as a function" 
   if $_[0] eq __PACKAGE__ && get(__SUB__) ne "method";       
   print "args = ", np @_ ;
  } 

  method meth_test ( @ ) { 
   warn "must be called as a method" 
   unless $class eq __PACKAGE__ && get(__SUB__) eq "method";  
   say "\$class = $class" if length $class ;
   say "args = ", np @_  ;
  }
}

say "\nCalling meth_test as method:";
My::Package->meth_test( ["foo", "bar"] );    
say "\nCalling meth_test as function:";
My::Package::meth_test( ["foo", "bar"] );
say "\nCalling func_test as a function:";
My::Package::func_test( qw/baz fuz/ );
say "\nCalling func_test as a method:";
My::Package->func_test( qw/baz fuz/ );
```

**Output**:

```
Calling meth_test as method:
$class = My::Package
args = [
    [0] [
        [0] "foo",
        [1] "bar"
    ]
]

Calling meth_test as function:
must be called as a method at FunctionParameters-PackageCheck-SO.pl line 24.
$class = ARRAY(0x801cfa330)
args = []

Calling func_test as a function:
args = [
    [0] "baz",
    [1] "fuz"
]

Calling func_test as a method:
must be called as a function at FunctionParameters-PackageCheck-SO.pl line 17.
args = [
    [0] "My::Package",
    [1] "baz",
    [2] "fuz"
]
```